# Missing LEGO instructions for this set from 2015

Tags: set-identification

I have 3 bags of LEGO without any instructions or boxes. The bags all say 2015 on them. I have attached a picture of the first bag. Any help in identifying it would be great!

[image: bag 1]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Judging from the beige 8x8 plate at the back it should be one of the ones in this list

http://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-4624223

Without seeing any of the other bags my first guess would be this one

http://brickset.com/sets/41101-1/Heartlake-Grand-Hotel[image]